# How to set the playback time from MPRemoteCommandEvent?

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, mpremotecommandcenter

I have code callback:

```
commandCenter.changePlaybackPositionCommand.addTarget { (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in

        self.player.currentTime = ???
        self.setupNowPlaying(img: self.image)
        return .success
    }
```

and it gets called. But how do I set the actual time where it should start playing from. The event does not seem to give me the time where the user dragged to. How do I get that value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The event does not seem to give me the time where the user dragged to

Yes it does. The `event` has a [`positionTime`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpchangeplaybackpositioncommandevent/1616766-positiontime).

Answer (score 2):

Cast the event as an MPChangePlaybackPositionCommandEvent.

MPChangePlaybackPositionCommandEvent has a positionTime property, which is the playback position.

```
commandCenter.changePlaybackPositionCommand.addTarget { (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in

    if let changePlaybackPositionCommandEvent = event as? MPChangePlaybackPositionCommandEvent
    {
        let positionTime = changePlaybackPositionCommandEvent.positionTime      
        self.player.currentTime = positionTime   
        return .success
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as shown above and for all the events you have to cast it to the event type matching the command then you get at the values.You get the time from event.positionTime after casting the event to MPChangePlaybackPositionCommandEvent
another example for skip is let event = event as! MPSkipIntervalCommandEvent